# How to allow a docker container to communicate with another container over localhost

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I have a unique situation where I need to be able to access a container over a custom local domain (example.test), which I've added to my `/etc/hosts` file which points to `127.0.0.1`. The library I'm using for OIDC uses this domain for redirecting the browser and if it is an internal docker hostname, obviously the browser will not resolve.

I've tried pointing it to example.test, but it says it cannot connect. I've also tried looking up the private ip of the docker network, and that just times out.

Answer (score -1):

Add the `network_mode: host` to the service definition of the calling application in the `docker-compose.yml` file. This allows calls to localhost to be routed to the server's localhost and not the container's localhost.

E.g.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: local
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${DB_ADMIN_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
  callingapp:
    image: <some-img>
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: local
    env_file:
      - callingApp.env
    ports:
      - ${CALLING_APP_PORT}:${CALLING_APP_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    network_mode: host // << Add this line
  app:
    image: <another-img>
    restart: always
    logging:
      driver: local
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    env_file:
      - app.env
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}

volumes:
  mongodb_data:
```

Comment: This generally disables Docker's networking; it means that inter-container communication using `app` as a hostname won't work, and you can't disable or remap container ports using `ports:`.  I wouldn't recommend it as a general-purpose solution.

Comment: @DavidMaze Good to know! Do you have a better solution?